# Почему MS SQL запрещает создавать процедуры если отсутствует колонка?

Tags: sql-server

В чем мотивация ограничения того, что нельзя создать процедуру, которая работает с таблицей и ссылается на колонку, которой нету, но я ее создаю при необходимости по некоторому условию?

Если таблица не существует, то это не мешает создания процедуры, которая что-то делает с этой таблицей.

Comment: это нужно для сохранения целостности данных, это контролируется на уровне синтаксиса

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Yaroslav, сомневаюсь... так как есть такой мощный инструмент, как динамические запросы. Т.е тоже самое, можно проделать динамическими запросами, и MS SQL и слова не скажет о том, что я обращаюсь к колонке, которой нету, только неудобно будет...

Comment: так динамический запрос как и не проверяется, та если что будет exception при выполнении

Comment: Не надо создавать колонки по условиям. структура БД должна быть постоянна

Comment: @Mike. Это понятно, но допустим если есть задача обмены данными и оговорено, что они будут класться в определенную таблицу, где я буду их разжевывать и раскладывать в мою БД, например, JOB'ом по расписанию. Так вот, что бы не городить миллион таблиц под разные форматы данных, я хотел бы динамически их забирать.

Comment: Если формат заранее не известен тогда проще хранить его в колонке json

Comment: можно создать колонку, затем процедуру, после чего колонку удалить.